# What is the solution to equation $\arccos\left(\frac{x-a}{x}\right) - \frac{a}{\sqrt{2xa - a^2}} = 0$?

Tags: trigonometry

What is the solution to the mentioned equation for $x$, given that
$a > 0$ and $\frac{a}{2} < x < a$ ?

This equation arises from an effort to maximize the perimeter of a circular arc, as illustrated in the figure, which is tangent to a rectangular strip at one side, and whose center (and subsequently the value of radius $x$) varies vertically.

[image]

I also want the center to fall inside the strip. Also a circle with radius less than $\frac{a}{2}$ obviously results in a circle with less perimeter than one with radius $\frac{a}{2}$. So I simply assume that $\frac{a}{2} \leq x \leq a$.

According to my calculations, since the arc perimeter, $p$, is equal to $x\theta$, and $\theta = 2\arccos\left(\frac{x-a}{x}\right)$ ($-1 \leq \frac{x-a}{x} \leq 0$), we can obtain perimeter $p$ as a function of $x$ as follows
$$p(x) = 2x\arccos\left(\frac{x-a}{x}\right).$$
Therefore
$$p'(x) = 2\arccos\left(\frac{x-a}{x}\right) - \frac{2a}{\sqrt{2ax - a^2}}.$$
Since $p$ is continuous on $\left[\frac{a}{2}, a\right]$ and differentiable on $\left(\frac{a}{2}, a\right)$, and also $p(\frac{a}{2}) = p(a) = \pi a$,
there is at least on point $x_0$ in interval $\left(\frac{a}{2}, a\right)$ such that $p'(x_0) = 0$. Therefore the equation of the question has solution.

My problem: I've got no idea how to solve the mentioned equation. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Thank you @TonyHellmuth. Solving this equation is part of an optimization problem, where I'm going to maximize the perimeter of a circular arc (with radius $x$), which is cut off a rectangular strip (with a width measure of $a$, and a minimum length of $2a$). At the end of my effort to optimize the perimeter, I was faced by this equation, that I've got no idea how to solve.

Comment: Write that in your question! :D Edit that beauty in ;)

Comment: Sure @tony. Thanks

Comment: @Hedayat There's no homogeneity. Maybe the numerator of the second term is $a$?

Comment: Yes @egreg. I double checked my calculations, and figured out that you were right. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set
$$
t=\frac{x-a}{x}
$$
the equation becomes
$$
\arccos t-\sqrt{\frac{1-t}{1+t}}=0
$$
for $-1<t<0$.

The function on the left-hand side can be seen to be decreasing over $(-1,0)$. Wolframalpha says that the root is, approximately,
$$
t ≈ -0.689157736645164...
$$
Use that
$$
x=\frac{a}{1-t}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much dear @egreg. This solved my problem. But I think you're making a mistake. The equation becomes $\arccos t - \sqrt{\frac{1-t}{1+t}} = 0$.

Comment: @Hedayat Yes, I flipped the signs. Fixed

Comment: Thank you again dear @egreg.